# Moodle - Como desmontar os blocks

Tags: template, moodle

Como usar os blocos para obter os elementos do layout?

Exemplo:

```
<?php echo $OUTPUT->blocks('course_summary', 'cssCourse'); ?>
```

Eu quero usar o bloco com o course_summary id, só que ele não aparecer na primeira página...

................................................................

Ou outra coisa que achei mais não consegui desenvolver mais em cima é isso:

```
<?php echo $OUTPUT->login_info(); ?>
```

Ele imprime o bloco de informações de login, onde dá pra fazer loggof e editar perfil, etc...
Mas não consigo mais sobre os outros blocos, nem desmontar o login info para separar por exemplo o avatar do usuario do nome dele...etc...

Continuo aguardando ajuda e exemplos...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui desmontar a área de login, para imprimir o bloco padrão é assim:

```
<?php echo $OUTPUT->login_info(); ?>
```

Para desmonta-lo em vários blocos há algumas maneiras, exemplo:

```
<?php echo echo $USER->firstname; ?>
```

Assim você desmonta o bloco login_info e imprime só o primeiro nome do usúario q aparece no bloco login_info...Para desmontar o resto é só seguir o mesmo caminho...